# How to use Firebase with Flutter without setup on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, dart, flutter

I am working on a Flutter application in which I would like to connect to Firebase for database usage. Google's documentation says that I need to run through setup instructions for both Android and IOS individually, and asks for a lot of information I don't have yet, as the app is in development. Because Flutter is cross-platform, I would assume there is a way to setup Firebase without this annoying proccess. In React Native, I was simple able to use

```
static firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxx",
    projectID: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderID: "xxxxxx"
}
...
if(!this.firebaseClient.apps.length){
    this.firebaseClient.initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);
}
return this.firebaseClient.auth();
```

and the Firebase model. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, the firebase plugins are not made purely in Dart, they are just a pass-through to get to the platform-specific plugins.

In other words, when you're using the official flutter firebase plugins you are using the Firebase Android plugin in Android and the Firebase iOS plugin in iOS. The plugins use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to make this bridge.

That's why you need to setup both.

A quick example: the [setPersistenceEnabled method, in Dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3897d4305492d658ed5a22570cbe36f3cb2ee73e/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/firebase_database.dart#L90), sends a message to a channel and either the [Android part will handle it in Java](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3897d4305492d658ed5a22570cbe36f3cb2ee73e/packages/firebase_database/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java#L264) or the [iOS part will receive it in Objective-C](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3897d4305492d658ed5a22570cbe36f3cb2ee73e/packages/firebase_database/ios/Classes/FirebaseDatabasePlugin.m).

However, as you may already know, Firebase can be accessed by a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/). So you can either access Firebase using this API or even create your own plugin which would only use the API instead of the platform plugins.